# Socket.io o utilizar setinterval para un chat

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Hola actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo nodejs pero me tope con problema referente a qué utilizar, ya sea setinterval realizar un get cada segundo o utilizar socket.io tengo contemplado montarlo en azure pero me preocupa los costos por tantas peticiones, se tiene contemplado el chat para unas 3mil personas diarias

Comment: yo te aconsejaría utilizar sockets, ya que usar un setInterval para llamar al servidor cada segundo o cada cierto número de segundos al final te puede realentizar el servidor, ya que si tienes 3000 usuarios en línea, serían 3000 peticiones por segundo, y en un minuto serían 180000 peticiones sin pausa alguna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente hacer un GET en intervalos es una muy mala idea, hace muchos años la técnica usada era lo que se llama "long polling", que se abre un GET tradicional a un servidor y ese servidor no cierra la conexión al cliente por un minuto o un "tiempo muy largo", si en ese tiempo llega algun mensaje entonces se lo manda al cliente y cierra la conexión. Pero aun eso es sumamente ineficiente para las técnicas disponibles hoy.

Socket.io es un framework muy depurado, yo mismo lo he usado en proyectos muy muy grandes sin problema, pero hay que recordar que Socket.io no es websockets, le pone un poco de azucar encima y tal vez use websockets de vez en cuando pero es más que eso, y por esta razón el cliente de socket.io es incompatible con un servidor Websocket. Lo menciono porque por ejemplo AWS ofrece una API Gateway para websockets, y es tentador tratar de conectar un cliente Socket.io a una de estas API Gateways pero esto no funcionará.

Websockets ya han madurado bastante y [aquí tienes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) una excelente referencia de qué son y cómo usarlos, te dejo un ejemplo

```
// Crear la conexión.
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Una vez abierta la conexión
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    // Mandarle un mensaje al servidor
    socket.send('Hola servidor de websockets!');
});

// y cuando el servidor nos diga algo
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    // lo imprimimos en consola
    console.log('Mensaje del servidor', event.data);
});
```

También me encontré [este tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/chat/get-started?pivots=programming-language-javascript) de cómo agregar un chat a una aplicación Azure que es bastante extenso para copiarlo aquí, pero si pones errores específicos que tengas te podremos ayudar mucho mejor.

Saludos